# Query Active Directory for distinct values in a given field (e.g. Country) via DirectoryServices

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, directoryservices, directorysearcher

I need to programmatically retrieve all of the distinct values in Active Directory for a given field (for example, the country field "co" - but I will have others) I don't care how many times a given value occurs or who/what it is associated with - I just need the list of distinct countries currently in there.

I have this which will produce the list - but for obvious reasons it is unacceptably slow as it is querying every record in AD and adding new countries to the list as it discovers them.

```
Public Function GetAllCountries() As List(Of String)

    Dim searcher As DirectorySearcher = ActiveDirectory.Forest.GetCurrentForest.FindGlobalCatalog.GetDirectorySearcher
    Dim searchResults As SearchResultCollection
    Dim properties As ResultPropertyCollection
    Dim countryList As New List(Of String)
    Dim country As String

    Try
        With searcher
            .Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(co=*))"
            .PageSize = 1000
            .SizeLimit = 0
            .SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
            .CacheResults = False
            .PropertiesToLoad.Add("co")
            searchResults = .FindAll
        End With

        For Each result As SearchResult In searchResults
            properties = result.Properties
            country = GetPropertyValue(properties("co")).SingleItem
            If Not countryList.Contains(country) Then countryList.Add(country)
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Return countryList

End Function
```

FYI `GetPropertyValue` is just a custom function I put together to pull the string value from the `Property` object...

Is there any way of using `DirectoryServices` (or a suitable alternative?) to query distinct values for a specific AD field in a more efficient manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no equivalent to SQL's `DISTINCT` in LDAP. And I see you're already doing what you can to make the search as fast as possible (asking for only accounts that have a value in the `co` attribute, and using `PropertiesToLoad` so only the one attribute is returned).

The only improvement I think you could make is to use a [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8) instead of a `List`. It saves using `List.Contains()` over and over, which [is an *O(n)* operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=net-6.0#remarks), whereas [it's *O(1)* with `HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=netframework-4.8#remarks). The improvement may not be noticeable if the list never gets that big, but it's worth a try, especially if this code needs to be run multiple times.

For example:

```
Dim countryList As New HashSet(Of String)(1000)
```

Then:

```
For Each result As SearchResult In searchResults
    properties = result.Properties
    country = GetPropertyValue(properties("co")).SingleItem
    countryList.Add(country)
Next
```

Notice that I set the size of the `HashSet` when declaring it. This saves it from [resizing as elements are added](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.add?view=netframework-4.8#remarks).

You also don't need to check if it's already in the `HashSet`, since [`Add()` just won't add it if it's already there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.add?view=netframework-4.8#returns).

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel - as I feared/suspected - I knew LDAP couldn't handle `DISTINCT` but was half-hoping the `DirectoryServices` library might have some nifty method that fudged it. The `HashSet` suggestion is very useful, though, so thanks for that!